# How do I hook up the `Tick` event to my Timer?

Tags: c#, timer

The timer's `Interval` is set to `1000` (so it will tick every second) and `Enabled` is set to `true`. I didn't place the timer with code but instead I placed it from the visual studio toolbox.

Neither the label Text nor the Debug console is being updated.

Here is my code:

```
public int sec;
public int min;

public Form1() //Constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sec++; //Seconds increase

    if (sec == 60)
    {
        sec = 0; //Reset Seconds
        min++; //Minutes increase
    }

    label9.Text = ("Timer: " + min + ":" + sec); //Update the label
    Debug.WriteLine("Tick " + sec);
}
```

Comment: Can you please also include the code where you set the timer and attach your event handler? And what is the exact effect? Do you see the Debug.WriteLine but not the label text? If you set a breakpoint in the method, is it hit?

Comment: Also, the timer is a rather low priority message, so it wont be fired *exactly* at the interval; you set.  So, you might be better off capturing the time at the start and subtracting the current time in the event...or using a stopwatch.

Comment: I have updated the post with more detail. It seems that the whole function isn't even called.

Comment: That's because, like Klaus said, I don't seem to see an event handler attached to the timer. You have to actually assign the timer handler for that event, otherwise, it will never be called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> An event is a message sent by an object to signal the occurrence of an
>   action.

In order for your method to recieve the event (doesn't have to be a method, it could be an object as well), you have to add a event handler to your `Timer` object like so:

```
public int sec;
public int min;

public Form1() //Constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
    timer1.Start();
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sec++; //Seconds increase
    if(sec==60)
    {
        sec = 0; //Reset Seconds
        min++; //Minutes increase
    }
    label9.Text = ("Timer: "+min+":"+sec); //Update the label
    Debug.WriteLine("Tick "+sec);
}
```

Now, anytime the `Tick` signal is raised, your method will be called by the sender.

[Here is some more information on handling and raising events.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)

[Here is some information relevant to the `Timer.Tick` Event.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick?view=netframework-4.7.2)